# How can I see the number of threads raised in a Parallel.ForEach loop?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

Given a scenario like this, running on a low power machine:

```
var logFile = File.ReadAllLines("logpath");
var logList = new List<string>(logFile);

Parallel.ForEach(logList.Batch(8), fileLine =>
{
    // work on the 8 lines
});
```

Is there a simple way I can find out the maximum number of concurrent threads that were spawned in the Parallel.ForEach process?

Comment: "ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads()" gives the difference between the maximum number of pool threads and the ones currently active. Didn't try it but could be worth a shot.

Comment: @RenéVogt Yes, that's exactly why I was hoping there might be some sort of built-in tracking via ThreadPool or somesuch.

Comment: The problem with checking availabe vs. used threads is: at which point/which thread should ask for those numbers. And of course, what other threads does you process use... so I don't think you get exact values that way.

Comment: @RenéVogt Ah yes, of course: I hadn't considered that the main program flow will need its own threads too.

Comment: The big question is of course _why_ you wan to know this... There is not much you can (should) do with the result.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I want to know primarily whether I can speed this up by throwing more cores at it, or whether it's already operating at capacity.

Comment: `whether it's already operating at capacity.` How will knowing how many threads it is using help you determine whether it is operating at capacity? Have you considered using https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Answer (score 4):

Track each thread within the loop, using Console.WriteLine or Logging.

```
Parallel.ForEach(logList.Batch(8), fileLine =>
{

    // work on the 8 lines
    Console.WriteLine("Processing {0} on thread {1}", filename, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

});
```

Comment: Of course I don't mind if you use this "idea", but the important part is really how to implement it. The way you show may be good for testing/research purpose. But if OP needs a productive solution, the tricky part is to store the IDs somewhere with the least possible locking overhead (as concurrent threads will access that ID-storage).

Comment: @RenéVogt Exactly. Plus, I want to finish the loop and see the highest number of threads that were running at any one time. Sorry that the original question didn't make this clear.